# Как найти максимальное и минимальное значения в ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<>();
        ar.add(12);
        ar.add(21);
        ar.add(111);
    }
}
```

Как найти максимальное и минимальное значения в списке `ar`?

Answer (score 10):

В пакетике `java.util.Collections` есть уже готовые методы на такой случай. Они так и называются: `max` и `min`. Остается только воспользоваться ими. Например:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(12);
list.add(21);
list.add(111);

System.out.println(Collections.max(list));
System.out.println(Collections.min(list));
```

**[Collection.max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-)**

**[Collection.min](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min-java.util.Collection-)**

---

Еще вариант стандартный: занести в переменные `min` и `max` первый элемент списка, затем проходить в цикле и сравнивать число на итерации с числом в переменных. Если оно меньше, чем `min`, то заносить его в `min`. Если больше, чем `max` — заносить в `max`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(100);
list.add(-666);
list.add(666);

int min = list.get(0);
int max = list.get(0);

for (Integer i: list) {
    if(i < min) 
        min = i;
    if(i > max) 
        max = i;
}

System.out.println("минимальное число: " + min);
System.out.println("максимальное число: " + max);
```

---

Еще вариант: отсортировать список с помощью **[Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))** и затем у отсортированного списка взять первый и последний элементы соответственно:

```
Collections.sort(list);

System.out.println(list.get(0));
System.out.println(list.get(list.size() - 1));
```

---

Есть и другие варианты, но этого тоже должно хватить.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь сделать циклы, которые будут сравнивать значения переменных и выводить максимальное или же минимальное значение, а также, можешь сделать это с помощью встроенного метода `math.max()` и `math.min()`.

Вот пример:

```
public class Test{ 

   public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.println(Math.min(1.123, 1.456));      
      System.out.println(Math.min(2.12, 2.0)); 
      System.out.println(Math.min(-5.2, -5.1));
      System.out.println(Math.min(0, -1.1));
   }
}
```