# Почему не срабатывает поиск максимального значения в ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Сразу скажу что нашел тему с правильным кодом, но не понимаю почему не срабатывает мой. **Прошу отнестись с пониманием так как я только учусь.**

Требуется найти в списке максимальное значение.
Мой код:

```
package com.JavaLearning;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sprint1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Double> temperatures = new ArrayList<>();
        temperatures.add(92.3);
        temperatures.add(12.4);
        temperatures.add(74.1);
        temperatures.add(45.0);

        double max = 0;
        for (double i = 0; i < temperatures.size(); i++) {
            if (i > max) {
                max = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Код почему-то отображает общее количество значений в списке а не большее из них.

Я нашел как изменить код в этой теме: [Как найти максимальное и минимальное значения в ArrayList](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648009/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-arraylist)

Если заменить содержимое цикла for на `(Double i: temperatures)` то всё срабатывает как надо, однако, в лекции по моему заданию используется именно подобное написание цикла for `(double i = 0; i < temperatures.size(); i++)`.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться что я сделал не так в своём варианте кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `i` у вас не температура, а фактически счетчик цикла (меняется от 0 до `temperatures.size() - 1`). В итоге у вас выводит не максимум температуры, а максимум счетчика, который равен 3.

Чтобы максимум температуры считать, вам нужно брать из списка значение по этому индексу.

Исправленный цикл:

```
double max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.size(); i++) {
    double temperature = temperatures.get(i);
    if (temperature > max) {
        max = temperature;
    }
}
```

Это будет эквивалентно такому циклу:

```
double max = 0;
for (double temperature: temperatures) {
    if (temperature > max) {
        max = temperature;
    }
}
```

Comment: Большущее Вам спасибо! Понимаю что для опытных специалистов подобные вопросы кажутся ерундой, но мне Вы очень помогли.